# JasperReports incorrectly calculates height of paragraph

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a report where I have paragraph with text, height of this paragraph is calculated by jasper - I am using "Stretch With Overflow" property.

In jasper preview I see this picture - http://screencast.com/t/VH4WdugLSdm - all is absolutely correct.
But in generated PDF file I see this - http://screencast.com/t/CV37qjtzuIj.
Last word is truncated. I think jasper has a bug in it, so it calculates count of lines incorrectly. Do somebody see something like it? Is there any solution? (maybe it is my bug, I need any hint).

These screenshots were made from Jaspersoft Studio, so I don't think that error is connected to wrong configuration of font extensions.

If you have any question - please ask - I will update the question.

Comment: What font attributes are you using for the text element?  The recommended setup is to use a font extension, which ensures that the same physical fonts is used in Java and PDF.

Comment: also this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304759/why-is-it-wrapping-text-in-jasper-report-6-3 and always as dada67 said use [font-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5773/font-extensions)

Comment: These screenshots were not done from my application, they were done directly from Jaspersoft Studio, so I don't think that it is related to font extensions.